# selected item in combobox not printing out when selected

Tags: java

I'm doing this project and it has I'm trying to print out the selected item in the combo box but it's not working. Just wanting to know why it is not printing out properly. trying to print "eric white"

```
 public void subList() { 
     //sets up sub list based on selection in managerbox 
     cboManager.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {    
         @Override
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
             if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                 Object selected = cboManager.getSelectedItem();
                 if (selected.equals("Eric White") ) { 
                     System.out.println("eric white");
                 }
             }
          }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Where are the other  closing parenthesis?

Comment: where are you trying to print ?? pop-up ? console ? web-page ?

Comment: @Ravi These of `ItemListener` would suggest Swing

Comment: But, question still remain same . where ? ;-) Because, `System.out.println` will print to console.

Comment: trying to print to console but its not working when i select eric white

Comment: @Ravi Sorry, misunderstood the question - since it's Swing, it should be printing to the console

Comment: @loganfearon So I did a really quick test and it works fine me, consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. It will result in less guess work and better answers

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the item listed in combo box is exactly "Eric White", because equals will look for exact string including space and case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `ActionListener`. Prepare for `null` value and case sensitivity.

```
 public void subList() { 
     //sets up sub list based on selection in managerbox 
     cboManager.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Object selected = cboManager.getSelectedItem();
             if (selected != null && selected.equalsIgnoreCase("Eric White") ) { 
                 System.out.println("eric white");
             }
          }
     });
 }
```